# How to read content using socket connection?

Tags: android

Can anyone please help to read content using socket connection?

I used following line of code:

```
 ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
 String message = (String) ois.readObject();
 System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);
```

Regards,
Monali

Comment: Why are you using Object

Comment: what to use..pls suggest

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet

```
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
    total.append(line);
}
```